# MessagingGateway info logged started twice

Tags: spring-integration

here is my log, why my endpoint started twice ??
my config problem?

```
61: 2020/09/16 15:56:20,288 4052 [INFO] [main] [integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:159)] : started bean 'transactionService.createTransaction.serviceActivator'
63: 2020/09/16 15:56:20,288 4052 [INFO] [main] [integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:159)] : started bean 'bank'
65: 2020/09/16 15:56:20,288 4052 [INFO] [main] [integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:159)] : started bean 'bank'
67: 2020/09/16 15:56:20,348 4112 [INFO] [main] [embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.start(NettyWebServer.java:109)] : Netty started on port(s): 8767
69: 2020/09/16 15:56:20,366 4130 [INFO] [main] [springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted(StartupInfoLogger.java:61)] : Started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested it and logs looks slightly different, but still the same in the final outcome:

```
2020-09-16 09:08:39,592 INFO [main] [org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] - started bean 'integrationGraphServerTests$Gate'
2020-09-16 09:08:39,592 INFO [main] [org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] - started bean 'integrationGraphServerTests$Gate'
2020-09-16 09:08:39,592 INFO [main] [org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] - started bean 'integrationGraphServerTests$Gate'
2020-09-16 09:08:39,593 INFO [main] [org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean] - started bean 'integrationGraphServerTests$Gate'
```

Where my `Gate` is like this:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "four")
public interface Gate {

    void foo(String foo);

    void foo(Integer foo);

    void bar(String bar);

}
```

So, we have 3 methods, therefore we are going to have 3 gateways. That's why we see those 3 `GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway` logs.

The last one like `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` is for the top bean for `Gate` interface proxy and its parser.

So, in your case you probably have 3 methods in the gateway interface.

We probably need to improve the logic in the `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` to mention a method name alongside with the bean name, so those start logs are going to more cleaner.
Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter! And contribution is welcome!